# Dual Boot Windows 8 - Ubuntu 14.04 with msdos partition table

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-8, gpt

I have a self-installed Windows 8 on a disk with a `msdos` partition table. I boot in UEFI, and I have a 350m partition with EFI file of Microsoft.

**1. Is it really possible to boot in UEFI with a Windows 8 on a `msdos` disk?**

From what I read, i thought the disk had to be GPT...

Then I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot. I used a live USB key install, started with UEFI. I have now an Ubuntu in a partition next to the one with Windows. Next to the EFI `Microsoft` folder, I can see an `ubuntu` folder with `.efi files`.

**Issue:** when I start my computer, none of the OS boot, I just have the constructor splashscreen.

Stuff I already tried:

- `boot-repair`
- set the boot flag to the linux partition
- UEFI with CSM in the BIOS
- `grub-update`

**2. Can Ubuntu boot in UEFI on a dist that is not GPT?**

What are my options, without wiping the Windows partition? (change my disk to GPT would wipe everything)

Detailed boot info : http://paste.ubuntu.com/13075035/

---

**Solution: use GPT.**

Comment: Where did you install Grub?

Comment: Why not just use gpt. It was my understanding that Windows only booted in UEFI mode from gpt partitioned drive. Ubuntu does not care. And MBR(msdos) does have a flag for UEFI (that is how installer works.) But some brands of systems have UEFI that only works with gpt also. So for those even installer must be gpt. Ubuntu can boot in UEFI or CSM mode from gpt, so it is more flexible.

Comment: I installed grub on the EFI partition, as well as on the ubuntu one.
@oldfred I would like to avoid GPT if I can, because I don't want to format my disk and lose the windows OS, that I used for a while already.

Comment: You have two drives, and Windows does not care if data is on a gpt partitioned drive. You can convert your NTFS data drive to gpt and install Ubuntu in UEFI mode on it. Or just install Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. Generally better to have each system on its own drive booting without other drive. and you still can share data on both drives in NTFS partitions.  Not without some risk so good backkups required: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html But you should have good backups before installing or reconfiguring any system.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first I've heard of Windows successfully booting in EFI mode from an MBR disk. Normally Windows will refuse to install in this way, so it's a mystery to me how you got it set up. (From a backup of a GPT disk, perhaps?)

In any event, your configuration is so unusual that if you can't fix it yourself, you're likely to be on your own. (Note that I'm the maintainer of the rEFInd boot manager and the author of the GPT fdisk partitioning tools. I point this out to emphasize just how far off the map you've gone.)

You can use `gdisk` to convert from MBR to GPT, but I don't know how the Windows boot loader will react to that change. Personally, I think that's what I'd do, given that the system has stopped booting with the Ubuntu installation, so there's very little damage left to be done, and you might as well fix the boot problem after converting to the more conventional GPT setup. If you do this, be sure to convert `/dev/sdb2` to a (`gdisk`) type code of EF00, which identifies the ESP. (It's currently an MBR type code of 0x0b, which is *not* the proper ESP type code on MBR.)

Comment: Yes, i had a lot of trouble installing Windows, I created a small partition to pley the ESP role, played with the Windows repair tools a lot and had a weird (but working) result. I formatted the disk to GPT, did a normal Ubuntu install that works, still have my windows partition and have good hopes to restore it! I guess I was tricked by a very strong warning from GParted about the data loss risk...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: GParted can't do an MBR-to-GPT conversion without trashing all the partitions, but `gdisk` can. It's just a question of what each tool was designed to do.